# Can you format display of a Smart Capture Form?

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, html, form

I want some fields on their own line and others to display inline. I built an order form landing page using the "Content Builder" option and added a Smart Capture Form with Data Extension as data target. In the code, each field is in it's own table and I don't have access to the actual "table" tag to apply custom inline styling.

I found that I can edit internal css and make the table class "stylingblock-content-wrapper" display inline but that makes every field display inline. I also found that I can copy field divs into the html of another field but if that field is edited, all of my changes are erased. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Unfortunately not, you are better off making your own form in my opinion, the smart capture feature from a design perspective is extremely dated and is long overdue for a makeover.

Comment: I was able to control the formatting by copying the form fields' code into one of the form field's html tab. If someone else were to edit that field through the WYSIWYG, all of my work will be lost. I'm the only one managing the form so it works for me, but I don't recommend this method for anyone else.

Comment: That’s why modifying the code is pretty much telling everybody how smart capture is lacking modern features and capabilities to create stunning and customisable forms to capture data.